# How do file-systems implement sector-locking?

Tags: java, filesystems, locking, shared-memory

*Though this is a general question, specific answers for any of the Windows- or Linux- or Mac- supported file-system(s) are welcome.*

How does a file-system prevent 2 or more processes from concurrent read/write access to a sector of a local drive?

I understand that some type of sector-locking would obviously need to be employed, but...

1. What would be the 'type' of this OS-wide sector lock:

   a) Named-mutex / named-semaphore / file-mapping ? (on Windows)

   b) Shared memory ? (on Linux)
2. Where is this sector-lock kept: In memory? On disk? In either case, wherever this lock is stored, I understand that...

   a) the storage for locks has to be a logically-temporary storage, since the lock should not be left dangling permanently or indefinitely if its owner process were to crash. So, it helps if these locks exist in memory.

   b) the whereabouts of the lock have to be publicly discoverable by all processes via a name or ID which found a function of the sector number. So, if process A needs to lock sector S, A should know how to first get access to the lock L(S) for sector S, create L(S) if it does not already exist, try to lock L(S), and either return or block -- all atomically, since another process B could also be racing alongside A trying to carry out the same sequence of steps.
3. For a large storage device, the number of sectors would be large too. So, a lock each for each sector cannot obviously be pre-allocated either in memory or on disk.

What I don't know or understand, however, is how this problem is already handled by ext* file-systems on Linux, FAT* and NTFS on Windows, and likewise for Mac.

*The actual context of my questions:* Ultimately, I have to apply the answers to the above for a Java-based, custom file-system that I'm writing using Java 7 NIO2 `FileSystemProvider`, where 2 or more independent Java processes could be accessing a bunch of sectors of the attached drive for reading/writing . In Java 7, the only non-JNI way that I know of to achieve shared memory between processes is via a `MappedByteBuffer`. But the problem is, this byte buffer would be 'raw' memory - whereas what I need is an OS-wide, mutex-type mechanism AND also probably a mutex each for each sector S. It seems, my changes to this `MappedByteBuffer` won't get carried out atomically OS-wide unless I also call [`MappedByteBuffer.force`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/MappedByteBuffer.html#force%28%29).

Would greatly appreciate all answers and comments.

Comment: What makes you think file systems implement sector-locking? What exactly do you mean by "sector locking"?

Comment: If sector is a shared resource which 2+ processes can concurrently read from/write to, then this resource,  just like other resource, in concurrent programming would need serialized access. This is what I meant by 'sector locking'. But even your brief counter-question (the way you worded it) was enough thought-provoking for me, so no offense only thanks!

Comment: Harry, filesystem operations take place in kernel mode within a driver. The driver synchronizes its threads with sync primitives, but there's no need for sector locking.

Comment: Thanks Eugene, but what would be the kernel-driver equivalent for a Java program? Wondering aloud, why the designers of Java have not considered providing an explicit "VM driver" facility where code common to all JVM instances can run.

Comment: At some point all I/O becomes serial. You seem to be worried about two writes to the same sector occurring at the same time. This cannot happen because the hardware can only perform one operation at a time. So the question is either: How do we prevent multiple processes from accessing the same hardware at the same time? Or, it has to do with some "higher" level of collision. Not all file systems provide this higher level prevention. The file system does not need to prevent the lower level collision, that is the driver's problem.

Comment: Dwayne, I understand that "At some point all I/O becomes serial", definitely at the h/w level. I am disappointed that Java has no concept of a "driver", a layer in which objects can exist as singletons and be declaratively shared across multiple JVMs. I hope Java designers are aware (or, become aware) of this problem and do something about it. Java is touted as a "platform", a "VM", and is anyway providing low-level stuff like DirectByteBuffer of NIO2, JNI, etc. But, sadly, no VM driver. The programmer should be able to decide whether or not a piece of code is shareable or not across VMs, IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're confused as to how a modern file-system is implemented, and older systems weren't usually multi-user; with that preface let's look at something called a [journal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journaling_file_system). Now there are some alternatives - namely

1. [Soft updates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_updates)
2. [Log-structured file system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-structured_file_system)
3. [Copy-on-write](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write)

However, the most common is probably a Journaling file-system. Which writes into empty blocks and simply moves pointers on completion of the write (while atomically writing to a "journal"), this allows for "rapid" recovery in the event of a power failure (or other write interruption).

As for locking your "journal" at the system level, I would probably use a [FileLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileLock.html) like so -

```
FileLock lock = null;
FileChannel channel = null;
try {
  // Get a file channel for the file
  File file = new File("journal");
  channel = new RandomAccessFile(file,
      "rw").getChannel();

  // Try acquiring the lock without blocking.
  try {
    lock = channel.tryLock();
    if (lock != null) {
      // GOT THE LOCK.... DO WORK...
      return true; // write success.
    }
  } catch (OverlappingFileLockException e) {
    // File is already locked in this thread or virtual
    // machine
  } finally {
    if (lock != null) {
      lock.release(); // Release the lock
    }
    if (channel != null) {
      channel.close(); // Close the file.
    }
  }
  return false; // Write must be retried?
```

Comment: I was certainly completely uninformed, not ever having looked into file-system implementations or even their internal design. You and Dwayne have given me some wonderful pointers. Thanks much. (I'll wait for a few days before marking your answer as final.)

Comment: Elliot, I'm more inclined towards implementing a journal. However, even with a journal, I'd need prevent 2 or more processes from trying to simultaneously append to it. In Java land, how do I get an OS-wide, cross-JVM mutex for maintaining the integrity of the journal itself?

Comment: You might use a [FileLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileLock.html); here's a [tutorial](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.nio/how-to-create-a-file-lock-on-a-file-4.html)